# Loading HashMap in Java

Tags: java, file, file-io, hashmap

I'm loading a HashMap like this

```
public void loadFromDefault() {
    keys.clear();
    try {
        FileReader fr = null;
        BufferedReader br = null;

        fr = new FileReader(new File("settings.txt"));
        br = new BufferedReader(fr);

        String s;
        while ((s = br.readLine()) != null ) {
            String[] sa = s.split("=",2);
            keys.put(sa[0], Integer.getInteger(sa[1]));
        }

        fr.close();
        br.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();            
    }
}
```

My settings.txt looks like that

```
k_close=1
```

I now access the HashMap `keys.get("k_close").intValue();` but I'm prompted a NullPointerException.

When I hardcode the `keys.put("k_close",1);` it works though. Splitting of the read line works properly.

Comment: If you call `System.out.println(keys)`, what do you get?

Comment: Have you debugged what is put in your list?

Comment: `Integer.getInteger` is not what you are looking for. _"Determines the integer value of the system property with the specified name. [...] If there is no property with the specified name, if the specified name is empty or null, or if the property does not have the correct numeric format, then null is returned."_

Comment: please show init of `keys`

Comment: Print sa[0]; Hope you are getting somewhere sa[0] <white space>

Answer (score 6):

You should use `Integer.parseInt()` instead of the `getInteger` method. That's what you need.

Answer (score 2):

You can use one of [Integer.valueOf(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf%28java.lang.String%29) or [Integer.parseInt(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29); the difference is that `parseInt` will return an `int` primitive while `valueOf` will return an `Integer`.